# How to fix the problem for the bleak module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, python-asyncio, core-bluetooth

Error running below code at `__aexit__`. Traceback posted below.

```
import asyncio
import time
from bleak import BleakScanner
from bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client import BleakClientBlueZDBus

ADDRESS = "EE:68:29:AB:6F:19"


async def main():
    global ADDRESS
    device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(ADDRESS, timeout=20.0)
    print(device)
    if not device:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("Can not find device...")
    else:
        async with BleakClientBlueZDBus(device) as client:
            for service in client.services:
                print(service)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I'm using bleak module for scanning bluetooth nodes, it works on windows but facing problem on linux.This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hai/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/hai/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 17, in main
    async with BleakClientBlueZDBus(device) as client:
AttributeError: __aexit__
```

Comment: Try adding `asyncio.sleep(60)` after running the main function and check if there's any output.

Comment: @Immaturetrader /home/hai/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py:53: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
  asyncio.sleep(60)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: You should not need to specify the backend to use. Bleak should do that under the hood. `from bleak import BleakClient`. Try using the following example to see if it works: https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/service_explorer.py

Comment: @ukBaz this is error:  [org.bluez.Error.Failed] Software caused connection abort

Comment: Are you able to connect to the device using `bluetoothctl` on the command line? Does `service bluetooth status` show errors? When running your script have separate terminals open with the following running to get more debug information: `bluetoothctl`, `journalctl -f -u bluetooth`, `sudo busctl monitor org.bluez`, `sudo btmon`